# using find in Bash Script and checking if file is present

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

```
 var= "$(find . -name 'gen*.bt2')" 


 if [ "$var" == "" ]
    then
         echo bad
    else
         echo great  
 fi
```

I get errors

**./script.sh: line 4:** ./gen.4.bt2
     ./gen.rev.1.bt2 
     ./gen.rev.2.bt2
     ./gen.1.bt2 
     ./gen.3.bt2
     ./gen.2.bt2: **No such file or directory**
great

However, when I run the same code in terminal, files are listed perfectly, without any error.

Can someone correct me, where am I going wrong?

I need to check, if certain files are present or not, if present then proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the space in your assignment. The shell is whitespace-sensitive. Your command is the equivalent of:

```
var="" "./gen.4.bt2 ./gen.rev.1.bt2 ./gen.rev.2.bt2 ./gen.1.bt2 ./gen.3.bt2 ./gen.2.bt2" # output of find
```

You need to remove the space:

```
var="$(find . -name 'gen*.bt2')"
```

Comment: @ jordanm
so silly of me. Bash is real bad when it comes to SPACES. Thanks much!!